# How to allow 1-9 a-z A-Z - _ % in url via htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I want to allow in url (1-9 , a-z, A-z, -, _ , %)

I have below code in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^shop/search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$  shop.php?search=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Issue : when space is passed in url
Example

```
domain.com/shop/search/my%20keyword
```

It is not working

Basically i want to allow `%` in url via htaccess
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> ... it is matched against the **(%-decoded)** URL-path of the request ...

[source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), emphasis mine.

mod_rewrite *never sees the %*, it decodes the `%20` to a space. If you want to accept `%20` in the URL then add space to the character class.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, nice primary source.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically i want to allow % in url via htaccess How to do it?

You can use this rewrite rule with negative character class:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/search/([^/]+)/?$  shop.php?search=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

`[^/]+` will match 1 or more of any character that is not `/` hence it will match whitespace or any other decoded character also that you want to match.